# Asp.net-MVC and AJAX. Don`t see nested list values

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

My problem is in sended data via ajax.

All ok, but coordinates of my list equals 0. But length of list is valid and equals 3.

I tried use JSON.stringify (with ContenType) on all data and only on nested array, but it didn`t help.

I also tried write numbers "48.30055320091479" instead of 48.30055320091479. It also didn`t help.

I have 2 models:

```
public class District
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Coordinate> Polygon { get; set; }

    public bool Deleted { get; set; }

    public District()
    {
        Polygon = new List<Coordinate>();
    }
}
```

and:

```
public class Coordinate
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public double Latitude { get; set; }

    public double Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

Control:

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AddDistrict(District district)
    {
        DistrictModelValidator validator = new DistrictModelValidator();
        var checkedDistirct = validator.Validate(district, ruleSet: "AddDistrict");
        if (!checkedDistirct.IsValid)
        {
            return Json(new { success = false }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            string statusMessage = districtManager.addDistrict(district.Name);
            if (statusMessage == "Error") { return Json(new { success = false }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); }
            else
            {
                var districts = districtManager.getDistricts();
                return Json(new { success = true, districts }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
```

and .js code:

```
var data = {
            Name: newDistrictName,
            Deleted: false,
            Polygon: [
                {
                    Latitude: 48.30055320091479,
                    Longitude: 25.914092659950256
                },
                {
                    Latitude: 48.30055320091479,
                    Longitude: 25.914092659950256
                },
                {
                    Latitude: 48.30055320091479,
                    Longitude: 25.914092659950256
                }
            ]
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "./AddDistrict", 
            data: data 
        }).done(function (result) {
            if (result.success && result != null) {
                jsController.data.items = result.districts;
                jsController.renderData();
                document.getElementById("add-district-form").reset();
            }
            else {
                jsController.getDistrictErrorMessage();
                document.getElementById("add-district-form").reset();
            }
        })
        .always(function () {
            $("#add-item").modal('hide');
        });
```

[colnsole.log(data)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4b79.png)

[How my code works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6PxT.png)

Requst data:

```
Name:adsadd 
Deleted:false 
Polygon[0][Latitude]:48.30055320091479 Polygon[0][Longitude]:25.914092659950256 
Polygon[1][Latitude]:48.30055320091479 Polygon[1][Longitude]:25.914092659950256
Polygon[2][Latitude]:48.30055320091479 Polygon[2][Longitude]:25.914092659950256
```

Comment: You need `contentType: 'json` and `data: JSON.stringify({ district: data })`

Comment: JSON.stringify means than i write contentType. Meanwhile via JSON.stringify control don`t work

Comment: Of course it does. Use the code in mt previous comment.

Comment: I tried exactly like you wrote. And it doesn`t work

Comment: it does. And I will create a fiddle for you later to prove it.

Comment: add images with proves

Comment: I assume you just abbreviated the code - have you actually included `type: 'Post'`? (which is necessary)

Comment: yes, and it still doesn`t work

Comment: Then you doing something else wrong that you have not shown us. Edit your question to add the the full code you have tried.

Comment: add full code with JSON.stringify

Comment: I wrote that it work without JSON.stringify. But it doesn\`t read coordinates fields (each equels 0). It is even reads a length, but doesn\`t values.

Comment: I have cut and paste you updated code into my project and it works just fine (I get 3 `Coordinate` items, all correctly bound). And it will not work without `JSON.stringify()` although you could also make it work by using `data: { Name: 'xxxx', Polygon[0].Latitude: 48.30055320091479, Polygon[0].Longitude: 25.914092659950256, Polygon[1].Latitude: 48.30055320091479, ... etc ... },` and remove the contentType` option

Comment: i have checked request and it is ok. Its asp problem

Comment: What do you mean _asp problem_? The edited code you have shown works fine.

Comment: I mean js code works fine. Asp doesn't fill or read nestet array values

Comment: It **all** works fine. And it will work fine for anyone else who tries it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are sending wrong data to action method.
You are sending object of following structure from js side,

```
{
    district : {
        Id : <id_value>
        Name : <name_value>
        Polygon : [<list_of_Coordinate_objects>]
        Deleted : <deleted_value>
    }
}
```

But on controller side your action method is expecting data in following format. (which is a structure of your `District` class)

```
{
    Id : <id_value>
    Name : <name_value>
    Polygon : [<list_of_Coordinate_objects>]
    Deleted : <deleted_value>
}
```

Thats why the data you are sending using ajax is not being deserialized properly on server side & you are getting wrong values.

Modifying your ajax code a little bit will help you fix this problem.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "./AddDistrict", 
    data: JSON.stringify(data)
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
})
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: i changed code like Stephen Muecke said, now it is like i wrote and work but coordinates of my list equals 0. I aslo add image how my code works.

Comment: As shown in your screenshot, you have received data for `Polygon`. It is now showing 3 `Coordinate` values but with no data in it. 
Can you check the data you are sending to controller using `console.log`?
I am suspecting property name missmatch for `Coordinate` values which can cause this issue.

Comment: Content of request:

Name:adsadd

Deleted:false

Polygon[0][Latitude]:48.30055320091479

Polygon[0][Longitude]:25.914092659950256

Polygon[1][Latitude]:48.30055320091479

Polygon[1][Longitude]:25.914092659950256

Polygon[2][Latitude]:48.30055320091479
Polygon[2][Longitude]:25.914092659950256

Comment: add all my debug data

Comment: @Rostyslav : I have updated my code above.
Use `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'` & `data: JSON.stringify(data)` in ajax. I have tested it on my system & it works.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution to your problem.Change your ajax to

```
      var data = {
          //  Id:100,
            Name: "akash",
            Deleted: false,
            Polygon: [
                {
                  //  Id:1,
                    Latitude: 48.30055320091479,
                    Longitude: 25.914092659950256
                },
                {
                   // Id: 2,
                    Latitude: 48.30055320091479,
                    Longitude: 25.914092659950256
                },
                {
                   // Id: 3,
                    Latitude: 48.30055320091479,
                    Longitude: 25.914092659950256
                }
            ]
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
           // dataType: "json",
            url: '/Home/AddDistrict',
            data: {district: data},
            success: function(dat) {
                console.log('success');
                console.log(dat);
            },
            error: function (dat) {
                console.log('error');
                console.log(dat);
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

and it will work :)

Here is my screen shot
[image]

Comment: No it wont. The collection will not be bound unless the data is stringified and the `contentType: 'json'` is used.

Comment: `contentType: 'application/json'`  will be used along with `JSON.stringify` .If we dont use contentType ,stringify will not work.